# file_put_contents path question

Tags: php, filepath

I want to create html page using php code form `c:\www\test\script\new\creat_html.php` to `c:\www\test\html\index.html`.

Now in `c:\www\test\script\new\creat_html.php` how do I set the path?

I use `dirname(__FILE__)`, but it just gets the parent path. How to? Thanks.

```
file_put_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . '/index.html', $html);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dirname(__FILE__)` will return:
`c:\www\test\script\new\`
you need
`c:\www\test\html\index.html`
so you need to up to 2 levels, you can do it with `..` symbol in path:
`c:\www\test\script\new\..\..\` = `c:\www\test\`
now you can add necessary part of path:
`dirname(__FILE__).'../../html/index.html'`

Comment: but my answer is more detailed. I'll upvote your answer, to share the rep :) it's just digits in database.

Comment: That's true,sorry I am so tired. I might prude you. hehe :D Thanks. I given you too :P

Answer (score 6):

```
file_put_contents("../../index.html", $html);
```

easy - simple

EDIT: You have to access creat_html.php directly, or this solution won't work !

Comment: @genesis, now I test in `WINDOWS`, when I uoload to a linux server, this `filepath` will no problem? Thanks.

Comment: @fish man, to use paths properly in Windows and Linux simultaneously, use constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of `\ ` or `/` in path.

Comment: yeah, I think so, so I choose `dirname(__FILE__)`, thanks oz_, few minutes later, give u the mark.

Comment: @genesis so in this case windows is more reliable :) *but I prefer linux for servers ;)*